# When I try to install matplotlab library getting the error mentioned in the description

Tags: matlab, python3, anaconda

When I try to install matplotlab library in my python 3.7.3, I am getting the below error,

```
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement matplotlab (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for matplotlab.
```

When I run the `conda list` command I can see

```
matplotlib                3.0.3            py37hc8f65d3_0
```

in the listings, Any ideas? Maybe the matplot lab for this version is not available?

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in the name of the library, the correct name is `matplotlib`

Run the following command to get it installed:

```
conda install matplotlib
```